# EF Core equivalent of T-SQL UPDATE FROM

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Is there any way to update multiple records via EF Core, to set a single property to different values in different records, without retrieving all the records from the database first?

I have two entities:

```
public class EmployeeDepartment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }

    // Other fields omitted for clarity
}

public class EmployeeManagerCompact
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to update the `ManagerId` fields in the `EmployeeDepartment` records from the `EmployeeManagerCompact` records.

In SQL Server T-SQL I'd use an `UPDATE FROM` along the following lines:

```
update EmployeeDepartment
set ManagerId = upd.ManagerId
from EmployeeDepartment tgt
join EmployeeManagerCompact upd on tgt.EmployeeId = upd.EmployeeId
where tgt.IsCurrent = 1;
```

Is it possible to do something similar in EF Core without retrieving all the `EmployeeDepartment` records from the database first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core 7+ [now supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete) `ExecuteUpdate` and `ExecuteDelete`, which can do joined updates and deletes.

```cs
var query = (
    from ed in context.EmployeeDepartment
    join tgt in EmployeeManagerCompact on ed.EmployeeId = tgt.EmployeeId
    where tgt.IsCurrent
    select new { ed, tgt }
);

await query.ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters
    .SetProperty(tuple => tuple.ed.ManagerId, tuple => tuple.tgt.ManagerId)
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Any way to do it with earlier versions of EF Core?  I'm currently stuck with EF Core 6.

Comment: No, just use raw SQL queries in that case.